# How to show total based on categories?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have sample table data in excel file like in this [link](https://github.com/udayrt/checkcloc/raw/udayrt-patch-1/springville.xlsx).

It shows total amount on top column by this formula =SUM(List[Cost]).
Can we create one more table right side showing total based on category and sub total based on type in it?

Tried different formulas like SUMIFS (=SUMIFS(ExpenseTable[Amount], ExpenseTable[Category], "electric")) but not working.

Please suggest.